# When I call a method in a class it overwrites the data in the instance of that call

Tags: c#, class

First off I've never posted any questions like this before so forgive any faux pas I make, I'm also new to programming so I may use some terms incorrectly.

I have a class called myBit which has one variable (which is an array of booleans called bits) and a bunch of methods. One such method is:

```
public myBit OR(myBit b)
{
    myBit a = new myBit(bits);
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
    {
        a.setBit(a.getBit(i) || b.getBit(i), i);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Where `getBit(i)` gets the `i`th Boolean in `myBit`,
and `setBit(value, i)` sets the `i`th Boolean in `myBit` to the value.

My problem occurs when I call this method:

`bits1.OR(bits2);` returns the correct value but also sets all of `bit1`'s Boolean values to that of `bits1.OR(bits2)`.  Why?

Comment: Also, have a look at http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the constructor for `myBit` looks a little something like this:

```
public myBit(myBit bits)
{
    this.bits = bits;
}
```

This is why; arrays are not values. If you pass around an array, then everywhere that uses that particular array will be able to change it and see changes made in other places. It sounds like you need to *copy* the array. If you're using .NET 3.5 or above, LINQ is the easiest way to do that;

```
public myBit(myBit bits)
{
    this.bits = bits.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: And thanks a lot to you too that saved me a lot of hassle copying arrays

Comment: @A Spoty Spot: No problem; welcome to the site! If my (or any other) answer solved your problem, please be sure to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. This helps others with similar problems find a solution more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, that is what your code is doing. `bits` is an array; so when you are creating your new instance of `myBit`, you're passing the reference of the array, not a copy of the array to  your new instance. Altering your new instance simply alters the shared reference to that array.

You would need to make a copy of that array to send to your new instance to make sure they contain separate data. This is known as a Deep Copy.